# Error in python3 using Tweepy : UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, encoding, utf-8

I want to extract some tweets using `lib: tweepy` . While printing the data, it was giving the error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1` then I `decode` it using `.decode('utf-8')` . But after a while, for reading it humanly, I wanted to `decode` it using `.decode('utf-8')` but it is not working.

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import json

print("awaisTwit")
consumer_key = '**************'
consumer_secret = '**************'
access_token = '**************'
access_secret = '**************'

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
lise = list()
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(10):
    data2= status.text.encode('utf-8')
    print(data2)
    lise.append(data2)

for i in lise:
    print(i.decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved by going to Eclipse -> Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Text File Encoding to utf8.